# how to concat a string with slash in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

The following is the script to rewrite file path to url path

```
tempFileName = rs("filename")
tempFilePath = rs("path")
domainname = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

realUrl = Replace(tempFilePath, "c:\inetpub\wwwroot", domainname)

response.write("http://" & realUrl & "<br>")
                 ^^
```

The last statement of the script with two slash, i don't know how to do string concatenation. anyone knows?

Comment: did you mean this : `realUrl = "http://" & realUrl `

Comment: Are you saying what you have doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have works fine so I suggest you save the file with a new name (for testing purposes) and update your code to

```
<%
tempFileName = rs("filename")
tempFilePath = rs("path")
domainname = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

Response.Write(tempFileName)
Response.Write("<br />")

Response.Write(tempFilePath)
Response.Write("<br />")

Response.Write(domainname)
Response.Write("<br />")

realUrl = Replace(tempFilePath, "c:\inetpub\wwwroot", domainname)
Response.Write(realUrl)
Response.Write("<br />")

response.write("http://" & realUrl & "<br>")
realUrl = "http://" & realUrl & "<br />"
Response.Write(realUrl)
%>
```

This will write out the value of each step, my suspicion is that the replace isn't working and you have undesired results (OP is not clear). This code also includes how to 'assign' the new URL to `realUrl`.